# Is there an automatic 'mouse clicking' library that can interact with a GUI?

Tags: windows, user-interface, python-2.7, mouse

I am disguising my real project by giving a similar project due to paranoia of getting fired.

I have a task that is the following:
I open a program that is a GUI. This GUI has 3 fields for numbers (age, height, weight) and 3 buttons (‘OK’, ‘print’, and ‘Clear All’). What this program does is the following. A user enters 3 numbers into 3 separate fields, clicks ‘OK’, and the program spits out the number of people in America that fit that description.

My boss has asked me to make sure that the program is working correctly. He said do the following ‘go through each possible combination, click ok, then click print. Collect all the printed out numbers, and make sure they add up to 350,000,000 (the entire population of America). This is basically what I will be doing for the next few months:
*   Click ‘Clear All’
*   Enter Age: 1 (month)
*   Enter Height: 1 (cm)
*   Enter Weight: 1 (Ounce)
*   Click ‘Ok’
*   Click ‘Print’
Start next loop:
*   Click ‘Clear All’
*   Enter Age: 1 month
*   Enter Height: 1 cm
*   Enter Weight: 2 Ounce
*   Click ‘Ok’
*   Click ‘Print’

I have to do each possible combination. 
My question is:
Is there some kind of python library which I can use to basically say ‘select this field by clicking here, enter number X, then select this field, enter number Y, then select his field, enter number Z, then click on this area of the screen (the area will signify the ‘OK’ button), then click this area (the area over the ‘Print’ button). Then click ‘clear all’ and enter X, Y, and Z+1.

Ideally, I would want to go through every possible loop while I am away from the computer.

Comment: Is this using a web application or a desktop one? What OS?

Comment: This is on a Windows Desktop Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) does exactly this, and uses Python as its scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

I found that pywinauto was exactly what I was looking for. I can click around and fill in fields in a GUI. The only difficult part was describing the buttons to pywinauto because it requires some special format, but thankfully thee is SWAPY which actually gives you copy-paste-able code that is a description of the button.

So pywinauto and SWAPY for the win!

Comment: +1 - thanks for taking the time to post your solution!